# How would I slow the overflow: scroll speed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used overflow: scroll so if a user were to click on a button redirecting them to the `<div>` below it would scroll smoothly. I feel that the scrolling time is too short and would like to know whether it would be possible to increase the time it takes to scroll down to the below `<div>`. Say if the scrolling time was 0.5 seconds, I would like to make it 2 or 3 seconds

Comment: not sure why closed, question is not just about smooth scrolling, but about speed of scrolling.  There may be another answer for that already, but the linked one doesn't have it.

Comment: @BlackICE I can see at least 3 other reasons why this question should be closed.

Comment: The duplicate tag and linked question should be removed if it doesn't answer this question as that is misleading to anyone that views this question in the future.